# Using parent div's scope

Tags: jquery, scope

In the following code on buton click parent div's input text is alerted. I'm not clear what it means "using parent divs scope. Can someone please explain me about this scope

HTML

```
<div class="info">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email" value="a@gmail.com" />
 <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
 </div>

 <div class="info">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email" value="b@gmail.com" />
 <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
 </div>

 <div class="info">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email" value="b@gmail.com" />
 <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
 </div>

 <div class="info">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email" value="d@gmail.com" />
 <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
 </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {

var $this = $(this).parents('.info');
var email = $('.email', $this).val();

alert(email);

});
```

Comment: as a side note use `$(this).closest('.info')`

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to get value of 2 element like this `$('.email', $this).val();`  or is it a spell mistake `$('.email ' $this).val();`

Comment: *"I'm not clear what it means "using parent divs scope."* The phrase has no particular meaning in relation to what you've posted, you'll have to ask whoever it was who used the phrase.

Comment: @Arun Is it wrong to use parents(). I'm new to jquery

Comment: did you mean `scope` or `context`

Comment: @T.J. someone gave me this code and said var email = $('.email', $this).val(); //this line uses parent div as scope

Comment: If this is the markup then so solution would have to use the .prev() method to get the email like `$(this).prev('.email').val()`

Comment: @user1671639 it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/4TSYt/

Comment: @Arun i have a lot of input fields in every div

Comment: that is why I noted about the markup... if the actual is different then `.closest()` is the way to go

Comment: @Arun code is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4TSYt/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment on the question:

> someone gave me this code and said var email = $('.email', $this).val(); //this line uses parent div as scope

Their terminology was incorrect, but what they were trying to say was that this line:

```
var email = $('.email', $this).val();
```

...will only find elements matching the selector `.email` that are descendants of the div inside the `$this` jQuery set, and then get the value of that element.

That line is equivalent to this:

```
var email = $this.find('.email').val();
```

...and in fact, if you use `$(selector, $this)`, jQuery will just turn around and do `$this.find(selector)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get directly the email

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    var email = $(this).siblings().val();
    alert(email);
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqakv/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will bind click event on buttons

$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
```

.

```
// this traverses the ancestry of that button until it finds an element 
// with a class "info", and then caches that jQuery object in $this

var $this = $(this).parents('.info');
```

.

```
// this searches for element with class "email" inside the cached element $this 
// (which is the parent as traversed above)
var email = $('.email', $this).val();
```

When you find element inside that of an element using the syntax `$('selector1', 'selector2')`, you are finding element with "selector1" in the scope of "selector2".

Answer (score 0):

```
var $this = $(this).parents('.info');
var email = $('.email', $this).val();
```

email denotes the value of element having `.email` class within element having `.info` class(where `$this` element is the parent element of clicked button).

Hope now it is clear.

You can refer [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) for better understanding.